# How to disable build-in Test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I created my model whitch is Test, and everything is working ok when I am using it within browser, but when I try to do something with it from rails c, I got error.

```
    1.9.3p125 :001 > t=Test.find(4)
NoMethodError: undefined method `find' for Test:Module
        from (irb):1
        from /home/dorijan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
        from /home/dorijan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
        from /home/dorijan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

So is there a way to disable this temporary? I know I shouldnt use this, but now it is too late...:(
Thank you

Comment: What do you want to disable exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know how to disable the Test module in rails console, sorry.

One workaround is to namespace your model into a new module and then at the console call from within its new name space see [how to here](http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/74-namespaced-models)

Answer (score 1):

Problem may be that you have used 'test' which is on the rails reserved word wiki as possibly problematic  see
[rails reserved words](http://oldwiki.rubyonrails.org/rails/pages/ReservedWords)

Try another model name not on reserved list

Comment: yes, I am aware of that, my question is, is there a way around it? I have gone too far in my project to change it all :( As I said, my app works fine, except in console...